# Select unique workplace - id combination in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following subset of my dataset that consists of approximately 22,000 individuals.

```
df<-data.frame( c("Den Haag", "Den Haag", "Den Haag", "Rotterdam", "Den Haag",
                  "Den Haag", "Amsterdam"),
                c("R007", "R007", "R008", "R008", "R008", "R009", "R009"), 
                c(20130101, 20140101 ,20130101, 20130101, 20140101, 20130101, 20140101), 
                c(40000,42000,22000,20000,38000,10000, 15000))

colnames(df)<-c("Gemeente", "id", "Date", "income")

df$Date<-as.character(df$Date)
df$Date<-as.Date(df$Date, "%Y%m%d")
```

In the above dataset, "Gemeente" denotes the place where people work and the id- variable is the person. My goal is to drop all observations that work in more than 1 workplace in my sample. Whether they work at different workplaces in subsequential years (R009) or in the same year (R008) does not matter. More precisely, I as well want to drop R008 for both years 2013 and 2014, because this individual works at two municipalities in 2013. So in this case, it means I will drop both observations R008 and R009 and are only left with R007.

I thaught I could do it in the following way, but I do something wrong with the unique command, which selects all unique ids in the sample while I only want to select R007. Does anyone knows what command I should use instead?

```
#Select unique rows of observations based on muncipality and id
library(dplyr)

#Select all unique combinations of Municipality and ids
test<-distinct(df, Gemeente, id))

#Select the number of unique ids (i.e. drop the ids that work at more than one place in our dataset)
#But here I only want to select id R007, but with this command I select all three. So this is where I go wrong.
test2<-as.data.frame(unique(test$id))
colnames(test2)[1]<-"id"
test2$nr<-1

#Use left_join to the initial dataset. 
dffinal<-left_join(df, test2, by = "id")
dffinal<-subset(dffinal, nr ==1)
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(length(unique(Gemeente)) == 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [1]
  Gemeente id    Date       income
  <fct>    <fct> <date>      <dbl>
1 Den Haag R007  2013-01-01  40000
2 Den Haag R007  2014-01-01  42000
>
```

Comment: `n_distinct()` is a faster and more concise equivalent of `length(unique())`.